# Javascript time keeper fails to update correctly

Tags: javascript, time, clock

I constructed a small clock out of Javascript code, and it fails to update correctly. It display's the time fine, but you have to refresh the page in order to get the clock to update correctly. Is there a way I can have my code update automatically without having to update the page every time?

Picture:
[image: The Clock]

```
<script type="text/javascript">

var currentTime = new Date()
var hours = currentTime.getHours()
var minutes = currentTime.getMinutes()

if (minutes < 10)
minutes = "0" + minutes

var suffix = "AM";
if (hours >= 12) {
suffix = "PM";
hours = hours - 12;
}
if (hours == 0) {
hours = 12;
}

document.write("<b>" + hours + ":" + minutes + " " + suffix + "</b>")

</script>
```

Comment: Use `setInterval(function(){....},3000);`

Comment: Your code is working correctly as implemented; nothing in it would cause the time to ever be updated, in other words.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, you could wrap your code in a function, say, `currentTime()`, changing the `document.write` call to a return statement, so you have a function `currentTime()` that returns the updated string.  Then save somewhere a handle to an HTML element where you want to show the updated time, like `el = document.getElementById('time')`, and then use an interval like so

```
setInterval(function () {
    el.innerHTML = currentTime();
}, 5000);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
function UpdateClock(){
  var currentTime = new Date();
  var hours = currentTime.getHours();
  var minutes = currentTime.getMinutes();

  if (minutes < 10)
   minutes = "0" + minutes
   var suffix = "AM";
   if (hours >= 12) {
      suffix = "PM";
      hours = hours - 12;
   }
   if (hours == 0) {
      hours = 12;
    }
   //document.write("<b>" + hours + ":" + minutes + " " + suffix + "</b>");

    document.getElementById('myClock').innerHTML = "<b>" + hours + ":" + minutes + " " + suffix + "</b>";
 }


 setInterval(function(){ UpdateClock(); }, 6000);
```

**HTML:**

```
 <div id="myClock"></div>
```

Comment: This will not work properly, due to the `document.write()` call.

Comment: @user876345 Thanks. However I've tried implementing the following code, and now no time is being displayed. Any idea why it's doing that?

Comment: I have updated my answer, please check it used to display the time